# Проверка условия слева или справа от игрока

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть персонаж и игровой объект. Нужно сделать так чтобы персонаж всегда смотрел лицом на игровой объект(в 2д измерении). Следовательно каким образом можно написать проверку условия с какой стороны от персонажа находиться игровой объект?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое экстремальное: проверять если координата x крайней левой точки объекта больше, чем координата x крайней правой точки игрока. Значит справа, иначе - слева.

Чуть более лайтовое: проверять если координата x середины объекта больше, чем координата x середины игрока.

Зависит от того, что более необходимо. В целом надо проверять больше ли координата X

Comment: чтото на подобии if(gameobject1.position > gameobject2.position)?

Comment: @ULYANARSL да, только position.x соответственно  и вроде go.transform.position  а не go.position (емнип)

Comment: Да. Все верно, спасибо